# How do I resolve an exception for exceeding maxJsonLength in JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, javascriptserializer

I have found a few answers that address this issue in the context of a large response, but none for my context of a large request. I get the following exception when posting a large file to an action method:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property.

This is before my action methods ever get hit, so the abundance of posts that tell me to set a higher json size on my response are all useless here.

The stack trace is:

```
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(String input)
at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: whats the stack trace when this happens?

Comment: @RobertLevy Added for posterity, but I have found a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extensive and panic stricken googling yielded one other poor dev with this problem, and the answer is simple but disappointingly invasive:

> [First you must build a custom JsonValueProviderFactory.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1751116.aspx?How%20to%20increase%20maxJsonLength%20for%20JSON%20POST%20in%20MVC3)

I copied dkinchen's custom code from his answer verbatim and it worked immediately.

I know this is a link answer, but the text of the link is a pretty good answer itself, I think.

Answer (score 1):

There are three basic methods of handling this depending on your current environment :

1. Setting the `MaxJsonLength` property default value within your web.config. (This will only apply to web-services that handle JSON)
2. Setting the `MaxJsonLength` property of a `JavascriptSerializer` object to perform your serialization.
3. If you are using `MVC4` to handle returning your `JSON` values, you may want to override the default `JsonResult()` `ActionResult` and change the maximum size manually.

Source & more info on how to implement these three solutions:   http://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/handling-larger-json-string-values-in-net-and-avoiding-exceptions/

Comment: No difference after adding that.

Comment: I'm not doing any serialization or returning any value at all. I get the error when I post to an action, even before the action code is hit.

Comment: The serialization is done by the MVC engine prior to your Action being hit. As you can notice from the exception, at `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize`.

Comment: I figured something like that, but until I found my answer, I was clueless as to how to intercept or configure the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue either by specifying keys in Web.config, or in Controller, or in both. Here are the ways:

1.) In Web.config, method-1:

`<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="214748364" />`

2.)  In Web.config, method-2:

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

3.)  In Controller while returning JSON data:

```
  var result = Json("Data", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            result.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            return result;
```

Comment: `system.web.extensions` is only for web services and not controller actions.

Comment: Is it? I thought i could use it for any JavaScriptSerializer class. I even searched in msdn for the same here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could you please tell me where to find reference for the same?

Comment: Moreover, instead of copying the whole long code to it work, first and third method of my answer always work. I have tried it myself.